# How do I let spring boot to use my profile in default?

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying run a spring boot application and I understand that i can use vm option to set my profile, but is there a way that i can set my profile in default so that i don't need to deal with the vm option? also can i let `mvn install` run my profile in default?

```
# my bootstrap
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: local
  cloud:
    vault:
      enabled: false

---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: local

---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: it
  cloud:
    vault:
      enabled: true
```

this is my pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Spring-vault-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Spring-vault-demo</name>
    <description>Spring-vault-demo</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--  my vault-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.vault</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-vault-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-vault-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-vault-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <argline>Dspring.profiles.active=it</argline>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>it</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

this is the error that i got

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'vaultPropertySourceLocator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/vault/config/VaultBootstrapPropertySourceConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'vaultPropertySourceLocator' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'vaultTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/vault/config/VaultBootstrapConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.vault.core.VaultTemplate]: Factory method 'vaultTemplate' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'vaultSessionManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/vault/config/VaultBootstrapConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'vaultSessionManager' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'clientAuthentication' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/vault/config/VaultBootstrapConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.vault.authentication.ClientAuthentication]: Factory method 'clientAuthentication' threw exception with message: Cannot create authentication mechanism for TOKEN. This method requires either a Token (spring.cloud.vault.token) or a token file at ~/.vault-token.
```

I try this in my pom file

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>default</id>
        <properties>
            <spring.profiles.active>local</spring.profiles.active>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

and
`spring.profiles.active=local` in my application.properties file

both of them are not working. still giving me a vault token not been set error.
I debug into it and see that the BootstrapApplicationListener contains an empty list for active profile.

I take Scott Frederick's advice, and i was able to run my local profile with `mvn springboot:run`. but when i run `mvn install`, it fail with the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for everyone who trying to help. so i find the solution. it is to use `spring.profiles.active=local` in my bootstrap.

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: local
  cloud:
    vault:
      enabled: false

---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: local

---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: it
  cloud:
    vault:
      enabled: true
```

again, thanks Mark Bramnik and Scott Frederick, appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Boot Maven plugin documentation [describes how to do this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#using.overriding-command-line).

For your example, you could configure this in `pom.xml`:

```
<project>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <profiles>local</profiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Also note that any configuration that is outside of a profile document (that is, above the first `---` document separator) is part of a profile named `default` and is used when no profile is specified.

Comment: Hi Scott Frederick, thanks for your help, appreciate it. I delete my previous comment because it contains some misinformation. so, after taking your advice and making the changes to my pom file. I see that `mvn springboot:run` is using the local profile and working fine, but i need `mvn install` and it is failed with the same error. It also fail when i run the application with intelliJ

Comment: when i delete config: activate: on-profile: local from my bootstrap file, and both mvn install work. I guess it is because the default profile has been using when no profile is specified as you mentioned. but it still run with default, not my local profile

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right, you want the 'local' profile to be always used when you start the spring boot application even if you do it without maven, like `java -jar my-app.jar`?

If so you could consider implementing `EnvironmentPostProcessor`:

```java
public class AddLocalProfileEnvironmentPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, 
      SpringApplication application) {
      // maybe some programmatic conditions here to decide whether to include this profile or not
      application.setAdditionalProfile("local");
    }
}
```

Now register it in `spring.factories` and check:

Inside `src/main/resources` create a folder `META-INF` and inside file `spring.factories` Place the following into this file:

```
org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=
  com.yourapp.yourpackage.AddLocalProfileEnvironmentPostProcessor
```

You can also implement the Ordered interface or use an @Order annotation if you want the post processors to be invoked in specific order.